# Imagick compositeimage is resizing

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I am creating a new Image using a lot of little ones, let me show you an example:

Those images (the ones with purple background):

[image: base images]

become this one :

[image: after-composite image]

The problem is that with the code below, I never change size of the images I am merging, so I really don't know why the images are resized while I don't ask for it...

I tried to change the Composite Operator [See documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.compositeimage.php) but nothing changed, always the same problem : the original images are resized before they are merged.

After doing this :

```
public static function mergeImage($layers, $filename) {
    $images = [];
    // Load all images
    foreach ($layers as $layer) {
        if (isset($layer['filename']) && isset($layer['x']) && isset($layer['y'])) {
            $image = new stdClass();
            $image->imagick = new Imagick($layer['filename']);
            if ($image->imagick) {
                $image->x = $layer['x'];
                $image->y = $layer['y'];
                $size = $image->imagick->getImageGeometry();
                $image->width = $size['width'];
                $image->height = $size['height'];
                $images[] = $image;
            }
        }
    }

    if (count($images) > 0) {
        // Define final image size
        $imgWidth = 0;
        $imgHeight = 0;
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            $imgWidth = max($imgWidth, $image->x + $image->width);
            $imgHeight = max($imgHeight, $image->y + $image->height);
        }
        if ($imgWidth > 0 && $imgHeight > 0) {
            // Create empty image
            $merge = new Imagick();
            $merge->newimage($imgWidth, $imgHeight, new ImagickPixel('none'));

            // Add all images
            foreach ($images as $image) {
                $merge->compositeimage($image->imagick, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, $image->x, $image->y);
            }
            $merge->flattenimages();

            // Write new image.
            if (!$merge->writeimage($filename)) {
                $result = -3;
            }
        } else {
            $result = -2;
        }
    } else {
        $result = -1;
    }


    $result = 1; // All went good
    return $result;
}
```

In fact, this is working perfectly with all tests, the only problem on this test is that Imagick is filling blank space with stretched images where it is leaving blank space in other tests.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Your code isn't a complete standalone example, and I can't understand what problem you're actually having. Can you clarify what problem you are having?

Comment: I can only see a bunch of smeared squiggles - please clarify your question as @Danack asks.

Comment: Ok - you've posted your code.....you still haven't clarified what problem you are actually having.